# Background is not getting 100% of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code:

```
<section id="servicios">
   <div class="container" id="whachado">
    <h1>ASDF</h1>
    <h3>ASDF.</h3>
   </div>
</section>
```

my CSS:

```
#whachado{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```

I've tried `background-size:100%` but it still leave blank areas around the div.

Comment: use container-fluid instead of container

Comment: That fixed sides but not top and bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body tag comes with a preset margin (I can't remember what the actual number is) but this needs to be set to 0 along with the h1 tag which also comes with a natural margin. The following code should solve your problem.

```
html,
body{
    margin:0;
}

h1{
    margin:0;
}
#whachado{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire background set to that color, then all you have to do is set the body background-color

```
body {
    background-color: darkslategrey;
}   
#whachado{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
```